# Best practices for user authentication for combined web app and api

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-jwt-extended

I'm working on a flask web application using flask-login for user authentication.
Now the current layout is going through some changes and it was decided that some of the components should obtain data from the server in order to update on user request.
I intended to create some api routes but I'm not sure how should I now handle user authentication accessing these routes.
I'll be happy to hear what's the best practice in these cases.

Thanks

Comment: Two options really, look up authorization code flow and implicit grant flow.

Comment: Is there a standard way of implementing the authorization code flow based on flask-login? I thought of creating an api authorization route - returning a jwt for logged in users to be used for the api auth. does it make sense?